# How to get filter query by dates and only get sum of fields and group them by dates in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, filter, group-by, relation

I need to get a query of Orders where between dates and group them by dates like Oct, Nov,..
and get sum of total_price and sales_count in the group.
I dont need the details of query , I just need the result of each group.

I want my blade table look like this:

```
row_numb | date | total_price | sales_count

1          Oct     200000         500
2          Nov     325000         650
```

I can get it like this:

```
    $orderGroups = Order::withCount('orderItems')->filtered($request->all())->get()->groupBy(function($val) {
            return Carbon::parse($val->created_at)->format('Y-M');
        });

        $orders = [];
        foreach($orderGroups as $order => $value){

            $orders[$order]['total_price'] = $value->sum('total_price');
            $orders[$order]['total_order_items'] = $value->sum('order_items_count');
            $orders[$order]['avrage_order_items'] = $value->avg('order_items_count');

        }

        return $orders;
```

I also need it to group them by seasons and 10 days. what would you suggest to handle this?

Comment: What you have tried? Post some code, so we can help

Comment: $orderGroups = Order::withCount('orderItems')->filtered($request->all())->get()->groupBy(function($val) {
            return Carbon::parse($val->created_at)->format('Y-M');
        });

        $orders = [];
        foreach($orderGroups as $order => $value){

            $orders[$order]['total_price'] = $value->sum('total_price');
            $orders[$order]['total_order_items'] = $value->sum('order_items_count');
            $orders[$order]['avrage_order_items'] = $value->avg('order_items_count');

        }

        return $orders;